# How to add jquery to open table

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a problem setting jquery to open table on click, i am not a developer yet so please be patient.

here is what i have(HTML, CSS)

HTML

```
<ul class="pricing">
<li class="list-item"><a href="#">1</a></li> 
<li class="list-item"><a href="#">2</a></li>
<div>
<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>
<li class="list-item dnone"><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li class="list-item dnone"><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.dnone {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

1. Add open class to the icon element and hide class to the li items.

HTML

```
<ul class="pricing">
    <li class="list-item"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="list-item"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <div>
        <i class="fas fa-caret-down open"></i>
    </div>
    <li class="list-item hide dnone"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="list-item hide dnone"><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

2. Remove/Add/toggle class on click.

JQUERY

```
$('.open').click(function() {

    $('.hide').toggle(' dnone');
    
});
```

3. Also you can add a bit of animation for the caret icon.

On click, add CSS class to rotate the caret.

JQUERY

```
$('.open').click(function() {

    if($(this).hasClass('rotate-180')) {
        $(this).removeClass('rotate-180');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass(' rotate-180');
    }
    $('.hide').toggle(' dnone');
    
});
```

Add this CSS declaration to your stylesheet.

CSS

```
.rotate-180 {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.